# Macro to insert a line in Notepad++

Tags: macros, notepad++

I am trying to create a macro in Notepad++ that replaces one line with two.
For example, this line:

```
M30
```

Should be converted to this:

```
G91G30X0Y0
M30
```

Comment: Your example isn't clear, but why can't you just start recording the macro, put the cursor where you want it, use the enter key to create a new line, and then stop recording the macro?

Comment: Could you do this more simply with find replace and/or regex? If you give a wider example of your before and after cases it'd be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Click search mode as extended

Use find replace

replace M30 with

G91G30X0Y0\nM30

If you want to record a macro, that also can be done for this action